# Inbox/reputation notifications do not work on chat server top bar

Tags: bug, chat, notifications, top-bar, global-inbox

On the top bar on chat server pages, e.g. https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/, the inbox notification icons do not work:

[image]

The dropdowns themselves do work and do show unread items, highlighted normally, but the unread counts do not appear.

Comment: Also, `/topbar/get-unread-count` on the chat server seems to return stale results until a site (non chat-server) page is reloaded. It's strange.

Comment: I put together [Top Bar for Chat Rooms](https://stackapps.com/q/7404/25350), and in doing so, it's become clear both why this isn't happening (most of the `StackExchange` JS object isn't loaded on the chat page, including realtime notification setup) and that it's also at least technically possible (the topbar JS has all the necessary mechanics, it's just missing the websocket, which *does* work, see script).

Comment: seems to have been fixed in the meantime, from what I can tell